# Android studio 2022.1.1 how to open window "project structure" twice

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2.
I have two projects open and I want to compare the settings in windows "Project Structure" which has all the settings of Modules/Dependencies/Build Variants.
This opens a modal dialog that blocks all my Android Studio projects which are open, so I cannot open this settings window multiple time to compare the settings from two different projects.

How can I open the "Project Structure" window twice from 2 projects at the same time so that I can view/compare/modify them at the same time?

I can only open one instance of "Project Structure" and so I cannot compare the settings from two projects.